Proxy not calling from netlify
i have added proxy like this in package json
 "proxy": "https://example.com/api/"
}

i'm calling my api like this
await axios
            .post(`/admin/login`, payload, {})

but after host my site in netlify it not considering proxy and get 404 error
Thanks in advance, please solve this problem.

add this to your netlify.toml file :
[[redirects]]
  from = "/admin/login"
  to = "https://example.com/api/admin/login"
  status = 200


This will not work. I've find one solution which is working perfectly
`
Redirect /admin/* to external API
/admin/*    https://example.com/api/admin/:splat    200
Single Page App (SPA) fallback
/*    /index.html    200
`
